# Selecionar dados de um PDO SQL SERVER para uma lista de select com PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Caros, elaborei este trecho de código para que os dados recebidos do meu banco de dados SQL SERVER sejam listados em um select através de PDO:

consultacargos.php:

```
<form name="cargo" method="post" action="consultacargos.php">
 <label for="">Selecione um Cargo</label>
 <select>
 <option>Selecione...</option>
 
 <?php 
  $consulta = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM [DB].[Cargos] order by Codigo");
 while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
  <option name ='selecao' value="<?php echo $linha['codigo'] ?>"><?php echo $linha['descricao'] ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
 </select>
    <button type="submit">Selecionar</button>
```

Até ai foi tudo bem, apareceram as opções na lista do select direitinho, só que o que eu desejo é que **ao selecionar umas das opções ela seja impressa na *mesma pagina* com um 'echo'**, vocês podem me auxiliar?

Acredito que seja algo simples, mas estou em processo de aprendizagem e fui indicado a buscar ajuda no stack para aprendizado.
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Na hora em que a página é entregue para o browser, acabou o serviço do php. Sugiro estudar sobre código server-side vs client-side em desenvolvimento web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso você pode fazer utilizando JavaScript. Aqui tem um exemplo:

```
<select id="combo" onchange="selecionar()">  
     <option value="0">Selecione...</option>
     <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
     <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
     <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
</select><br><br>
<div id="resultado">Aqui vai aparecer o valor selecionado<br>

<script type="text/javascript">
function selecionar() {
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = document.getElementById("combo").value;
    }
</script>
```